# Java class without constructor, only static functions

Tags: java, constructor

I have created the class angle as shown in the codebox below, I want to calculate the difference( called "minus" in the code) of two angles with the following command.

```
Angle.degrees(135).minus(Angle.degrees(90)).getDegrees()
```

Unfortunately, I always get zero as result, because the intern values are always overwritten.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Angle {

    private static double gradmass = 0;
    private static double bogenmass = 0;

    public static Angle degrees(double angle) {
        Angle angleD = new Angle();

       //  gradmass = angle;
       //  bogenmass = Math.toRadians(angle);

        angleD.setDegrees(angle);
        angleD.setRadians(Math.toRadians(angle));
        return angleD;
    }

    public static Angle radians(double angle) {
        Angle angleR = new Angle();

        // gradmass = Math.toDegrees(angle);
        // bogenmass = angle;

        angleR.setDegrees(Math.toDegrees(angle));
        angleR.setRadians(angle);
        return angleR;
    }

    public double getDegrees() {
        return gradmass;
    }

    public void setDegrees(double gradM) {
        gradmass = gradM;

    }

    public double getRadians() {
        return bogenmass;
    }

    public void setRadians(double bogenM) {
        bogenmass = bogenM;
    }

    public Angle plus(Angle other) {
        Angle temp = new Angle();

        temp.setDegrees(this.getDegrees() + other.getDegrees());
        temp.setRadians(other.getRadians() + other.getRadians());

        return temp;
    }

    public Angle minus(Angle other) {
        Angle temp = new Angle();;

        temp.setDegrees(this.getDegrees() - other.getDegrees());
        temp.setRadians(this.getRadians() - other.getRadians());

        return temp;
    }

    public Angle neg() {
        Angle temp = new Angle();
        temp.setDegrees(-this.getDegrees());
        temp.setRadians(-this.getRadians());
        return temp;
    }

    public double sin() {
        double temp;
        temp = Math.sin(this.getDegrees());
        return temp;
    }

    public double cos() {
        double temp;
        temp = Math.cos(this.getDegrees());
        return temp;
    }

    public boolean similarTo(Angle other){
        boolean gleich = false;
        if( 0 == (this.getDegrees() - other.getDegrees()) || this.neg().getDegrees() == other.getDegrees()){
            gleich = true;
        }
        return gleich;

    }

    public String toString(){
        return
                "GradM " + this.getDegrees() + " BogenM " + this.getRadians();
    }
}
```

I did not make a constructor on purpose! I'm looking for a solution without a constructor or nonstatic methods.

Comment: You need **non static attributes**

Comment: Don't do that. Your class and calculation will not be thread save. You will never be able to rely on the result. Use instance variables and instance methods instead.

Comment: Btw: Your class has a no-arg constructor inherited from `Object`. Even if you don't explicitly specify it, because every class inherits from `Object`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both your data members are static, meaning there's a single instance of them for the entire class. You should declare them as instance members so that each instance of `Angle` can have its own values:

```java
public class Angle {

    private double gradmass = 0;
    private double bogenmass = 0;
   
    // rest of the code...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this. Your class won't be thread-safe this way. What you want is kind of something like BigDecimal class in java, I guess. You can check the documentation of BigDecimal class of java if you want something like this.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

But if you want the exact same thing you asked, you can see this (not thread safe and not recommended as well).

```
class Angle {
    static Double angle1 = null;
    static Double angle2 = null;
    private static void setAngle(double angle) {
        if (angle1 == null) angle1 = angle;
        else angle2 = angle; 
    }
    static Angle degrees(Double angle) {
        setAngle(angle);
        return new Angle();
    }
    static Double getDegrees() {
        return angle1;
    }
    static Angle minus(Angle angle) {
        angle1 -= angle2;
        return new Angle();
    }
}

public class SolutionAngle {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(Angle.degrees(135).minus(Angle.degrees(90)).getDegrees());
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the way to do this.   The solution is for the fields to not be static so the Angle object returned from the degrees and minus methods are real objects that hold the value.  If the developer doesn't want the constructor to be used externally it should be made private.  You are returning empty token objects that don't serve a useful purpose. You have most certainly not made anything "thread safe".

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.